# reactjs apex charts not loading array into series for chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I'm using apex charts for react in my reactJS progressive web app, and have had no issues with it for static data, but I"m now trying to take a returned array from my database and use the array for the graph and it's not working.

I'm logging the array returned from the database, which is in this structure:

[image]

And in my code, I'm setting this to the third series option of my chart named "Trends" but when the graph loads the line for that data is 'Nan'

What am I doing wrong here?

```
class TrendsComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  maxCalories: '',
  calorieRecord: {
        caloriesConsumed: '',
        caloriesBurned: '',
        createdAt: undefined,
        updatedAt: undefined
  },
  options: {

    fill: {
      colors: ['#FF756D', '#85DE77', '#FFF49C']
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      textAnchor: 'middle',
      distributed: false,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      style: {
          fontSize: '14px',
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          colors: ["#FF756D", "#85DE77", "#FFF49C"]
      },
      background: {
        enabled: true,
        foreColor: '#fff',
        padding: 4,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#fff',
        opacity: 0.9,
      },
      dropShadow: {
          enabled: true,
          top: 1,
          left: 1,
          blur: 1,
          color: '#000',
          opacity: 0.8
      }
    },
    colors: ["#FF756D", "#85DE77", "#FFF49C"],
    chart: {
      toolbar: {
        show:false
      },
      id: "basic-bar"
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: ['3/20', '3/21', '3/22', '3/23', '3/24', '3/25','3/26']
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "Baseline",
      data: [250,500,234,389,644,245,590]
    },
    {
      name: "Optimal",
      data: [2250,2250,2250,2250,2250,2250,2250]
    },
    {
      //this is the line where I'm getting NaN
      name: "Trend (tracked)",
      data: [this.maxCalories]
    }
  ]
};
}
...
```

UPDATE:

Upon component mounting, I use these functions to set MaxCalories which is the data array I'm using for the chart

```
getMax = () => {

    this.state.caloriesDB.db.createIndex({
      index: {
        fields: ['_id','caloriesBurned']
      }
    }).then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setMax();

   }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  setMax = () => {
    this.state.caloriesDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {caloriesBurned: {$exists: true}},
        ]
      },
      fields: ['caloriesBurned'],
      sort: [{'_id':'desc'}],
      limit: 7
    }).then(result => {
      console.log('max');
      console.log(result);
      const newDocs = result.docs;
      this.setState({
        maxCalories: newDocs.map(docs => docs)
      });
      console.log('maxCalories');
      console.log(this.state.maxCalories);

    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you please show how you are loading the data and which line is having issues with `NaN`?

Comment: @norbitrial I've added a comment where I'm getting the NaN. I'll update with the database code

Comment: @norbitrial just added the code that gets the array

Comment: @norbitrial is the issue due to having 7 array indeces with my data, as opposed to one array with 7 elements?

Comment: I think `this.maxCalories` makes the issue here. Probably that's `undefined`.

Comment: but this.state.maxCalories errors out, so that's why I used this.maxCalories. If I just log this.state.maxCalories I get what's in the image above

Comment: @norbitrial since the chart options are in state, it won't allow me to use this.state

Comment: So I finally reduced my original map with ```const result = data.map(x => +x.caloriesBurned) ``` which gave me [123,321,433,567,876,977,823] and I set this as maxCalories but I still get undefined. Is it because maxCalories and series are in state but I set maxCalories in a function within componentDidMount?

Comment: @norbitrial does my last comment make sense